# Windows GUI software for georeferencing, projecting and converting PDS 3 files

Tags: windows, data-analysis, gis

I need to georeference, project and convert Chandrayaan HYSI PDS 3 datasets into geotiff. I need a simple gui with less commandline interface software running on windows platform to do the job.